# Is any proper subvariety contained in hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Suppose $A$ is a subvariety of an irreducible complex space(analytic variety) $X$. Is there an analytic hypersurface of $X$ containing $A$?

Comment: If I understand the terminology correctly, no. There are examples of 2-dimensional compact complex manifolds $X$ which contain no compact analytic subvarieties of dimension 1. For such an $X$, take $A$ to be any point in $X$.

Comment: In the algebraic category, this is true. Just take any generator of the ideal of $A$.

Comment: @Pop Thanks. Non-abealian complex torus is in this case.

Comment: Also at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952462/is-any-proper-analytic-subvariety-contained-in-an-analytic-hypersurface).